# What causes the WIX error: 'The "GenerateHarvestedSourceFiles" task failed unexpectedly.'?

Tags: wix, heat

I am seeing this error in some of my .wixproj project files being compiled in Visual Studio 2015 using WiX Toolset v3.11.0.1701 and WiX Expansion Pack v3.11.26.   The stack trace is of a duplicate key insertion error.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\FireGiant.HeatWave.targets(70,5): error MSB4018: The "GenerateHarvestedSourceFiles" task failed unexpectedly. 
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\FireGiant.HeatWave.targets(70,5): error MSB4018: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. 
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\FireGiant.HeatWave.targets(70,5): error MSB4018:    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) 
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\FireGiant.HeatWave.targets(70,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) 
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\FireGiant.HeatWave.targets(70,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) 
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\FireGiant.HeatWave.targets(70,5): error MSB4018:    at FireGiant.HeatWave.Harvesting.ExpandHarvestDirectivesCommand.ExpandComponentElement(XName directiveType, String directiveId, WixComponent element, IEnumerable`1 files, String keyId, String keyPathNameSeed, HeatWaveHarvestStrategy strategy, Boolean suppressFont, Dictionary`2 generatedFolders) 
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\FireGiant.HeatWave.targets(70,5): error MSB4018:    at FireGiant.HeatWave.Harvesting.ExpandHarvestDirectivesCommand.ExpandElement(XName directiveType, String directiveId, String documentPath, WixElement element, IEnumerable`1 files, String keyId, String keyPathNameSeed, HeatWaveHarvestStrategy strategy, Boolean suppressFont, Dictionary`2 generatedFolders) 
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\FireGiant.HeatWave.targets(70,5): error MSB4018:    at FireGiant.HeatWave.Harvesting.ExpandHarvestDirectivesCommand.Execute() 
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\FireGiant.HeatWave.targets(70,5): error MSB4018:    at FireGiant.HeatWave.Harvesting.Commands.HarvestToSourceFilesCommand.ExpandDocumentsWithHarvestDirectives(IEnumerable`1 directives) 
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\FireGiant.HeatWave.targets(70,5): error MSB4018:    at FireGiant.HeatWave.Harvesting.Commands.HarvestToSourceFilesCommand.Execute() 
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\FireGiant.HeatWave.targets(70,5): error MSB4018:    at FireGiant.HeatWave.Harvesting.GenerateHarvestedSourceFiles.Execute() 
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\FireGiant.HeatWave.targets(70,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() 
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\FireGiant.HeatWave.targets(70,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Check if you have any file element in your wix file with duplicate "Id" attribute.

Comment: @PankajKapare Thanks but I checked for that.  More background:  this .wixproj was working before a re-organization of the source code directories.  The reorg resulted in the project source files not being in the directory tree of the .wxs files.

Comment: Contact FireGiant support (support@firegiant.com) for support on WEP.